# CKEditor - retrieve data as text instead of html

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor to allow user to create HTML templates and save in database. I would actually have 2 types of templates - **HTML** & **TEXT**.
I am using CKEditor to manage template content. Now the problem is that I am able to save HTML tempaltes, but not text templates.
I currently use `editor.getdata()` in javascript to extract HTML content. How can I use CKEditor to return the text content?

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().getText()
```

reference:
http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Can-I-get-editors-data-plain-text-format

Comment: thanks for answer, i modified code to get html editor.document.getBody().getHtml();

Comment: Crashes if you are in <source> mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data from ckeditor then use this code in your controller/js file:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editorHtmlAdmin.getData();
```

editorHtmlAdmin is the id of that inputbox / textarea:

**Use in html like this:**

```
<textarea  name="descriptionForProfile" id="editorHtmlAdmin" rows="4" />
```

**If you want to set some data in the ckditor then you should use this code:**

```
        CKEDITOR.instances['editorHtmlAdmin'].setData("TEST DATA");
```

editorHtmlAdmin is the id of that inputbox / textarea:

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.element.getText()
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give some explanation as to WHY your answer is the one.